# mvc3/razor String.Format("{0:c}", totalprice) returns no decimal or numbers after it

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, sql-server-ce

Maybe a fresh set of eyes can help. I have been at it for hours trying different things and this was the only one that had a close result to what i want.

Table:

- The Price Field is set as `money` with values like `3.99`,`4.99`,`17.99`

Code:

```
var totalprice = (int)db.QueryValue(@"SELECT SUM(CoverPrice) FROM Comics WHERE Approved='1' AND ArcId = @0", aId);
```

Call it with:

```
@String.Format("{0:c}", totalprice)
```

Which outputs:

```
$26
```

But I want it to print out with the decimal and the 2 numbers after it which should be `26.97`. What did I miss???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you cast your `totalprice` variable to an int.

Change

```
var totalprice = (int)db.QueryValue(@"SELECT SUM(CoverPrice) FROM Comics WHERE Approved='1' AND ArcId = @0", aId);
```

to

```
var totalprice = (decimal)db.QueryValue(@"SELECT SUM(CoverPrice) FROM Comics WHERE Approved='1' AND ArcId = @0", aId);
```

Comment: See told you fresh eyes is what i needed... lol... thanks man... sometimes i amaze myself!!!

Comment: No problem ;) I know what you mean. Glad to help! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

When you cast the amount as int, you lost the cents, you need to cast it as decimal:

```
var totalprice = (decimal)db.QueryValue(@"SELECT SUM(CoverPrice) FROM Comics WHERE Approved='1' AND ArcId = @0", aId);
```